# torch_geometric module not found

Tags: pytorch-geometric

While using `import torch_geometric` I get a module not found error from torch_geometric.data. `import torch` runs without an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import torch_geometric

File ~\anaconda3\envs\python3_8_10\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\__init__.py:4
      1 from types import ModuleType
      2 from importlib import import_module
----> 4 import torch_geometric.data
      5 import torch_geometric.loader
      6 import torch_geometric.transforms

File ~\anaconda3\envs\python3_8_10\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\data\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .data import Data
      2 from .hetero_data import HeteroData
      3 from .temporal import TemporalData

File ~\anaconda3\envs\python3_8_10\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\data\data.py:20
     18 import torch
     19 from torch import Tensor
---> 20 from torch_sparse import SparseTensor
     22 from torch_geometric.data.feature_store import (
     23     FeatureStore,
     24     FeatureTensorType,
     25     TensorAttr,
     26     _field_status,
     27 )
     28 from torch_geometric.data.graph_store import (
     29     EDGE_LAYOUT_TO_ATTR_NAME,
     30     EdgeAttr,
   (...)
     34     edge_tensor_type_to_adj_type,
     35 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\python3_8_10\lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\__init__.py:19
     17 spec = cuda_spec or cpu_spec
     18 if spec is not None:
---> 19     torch.ops.load_library(spec.origin)
     20 else:  # pragma: no cover
     21     raise ImportError(f"Could not find module '{library}_cpu' in "
     22                       f"{osp.dirname(__file__)}")

File ~\anaconda3\envs\python3_8_10\lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py:255, in _Ops.load_library(self, path)
    250 path = torch._utils_internal.resolve_library_path(path)
    251 with dl_open_guard():
    252     # Import the shared library into the process, thus running its
    253     # static (global) initialization code in order to register custom
    254     # operators with the JIT.
--> 255     ctypes.CDLL(path)
    256 self.loaded_libraries.add(path)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\python3_8_10\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:381, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    378 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
    380 if handle is None:
--> 381     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382 else:
    383     self._handle = handle

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\fes33\anaconda3\envs\python3_8_10\Lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\_convert_cuda.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to install some package.

## Step 1: Check for your python version and torch version

### 1.1 torch version

```py
import torch

print("torch version: ", torch.__version__)
```

### 1.2 Python version

```
python -V
```

## Step 2: Install some package

### 2.1 Check your OS type

There has Windows / Linux OS for those packages

### 2.2 Install packages

[Package link for torch_geometric](https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/)

### 2.3 Example

For me, I'm using Linux with torch version `1.13.1`. And python version `3.7`.

And I needs to use with CUDA.

I needs to install four of those packages

[image]

After all, using `pip install` for four of packages.

## Step 3: Install main library

```
pip install torch-geometric
```

And then you can use this library now. Cheers ~

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

just add it as the first code line when you execute your code:

!pip install -q git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git

( hope it works :) )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).